# htaccess: How to display GET variables?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have code that displays news. but now I want to use `.htaccess` to hide the `id=2` bla..
Everything is working fine but It doesn't display the get variables

I have tried using `[L,QSA]`, `[NC,QSA]` none is working

//get variables

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id        = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt_edit = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id =:uid');
    $stmt_edit->execute(array(
        ':uid' => $id
    ));
    $edit_row  = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $image     = $edit_row['headline_image'];
    $article   = $edit_row['article_body'];
    $headlines = $edit_row['headlines'];
    $date      = $edit_row['date'];
    $month     = $edit_row['month'];
    $admin     = $edit_row['admin'];
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

//.htaccess code

```
Options  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?id=$newsid [L,QSA]
```

I am using the variables outside the get functions I want to to display the content of the respective variable.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `$_GET['id']` contains? (That should have given you a clue.)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?id=$newsid [L,QSA]
> ```

Why `$newsid`? `$newsid` is seen as a literal string here, so `$id` (ie. `$_GET['id']`) in your PHP code will be always be the literal string `"$newsid"` (but presumably you saw this while debugging your PHP code?)

You should be using the `$1` backreference instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

*Aside:* You may also want an end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, as otherwise this will match `/news/123anything`. Or maybe that's the intention?